# A story about Earth in far future with a civilization centered around a huge tree

Tags: story-identification, books

I'd like to ask you to help me identify a sci-fi/fantasy book that I read probably sometime in the 90s though I don't know when it was written. Here are the plot points that I remember:

- the story starts with a human on contemporary Earth being turned to stone (or probably something much more exotic) by some sort of experiment gone wrong,
- he is turned back to his original form millions of years later by a lightning or some similar phenomenon,
- the local population considers him a god or a prophet since his "stone form" was a center of a cult before he was awaken,
- the population is not human but consists of creatures evolved from various contemporary animals,
- one of the most important locations is a huge tree which is so ridiculously big that it contains multiple settlements.

Comment: Possible dupe of an earlier question about an intelligent forest http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/45413/title-author-search-read-late-70s-last-human-revived-from-stasis-intelligent

Comment: The first few sentences seem to be spot on, but the rest sounds unfamiliar (though I don't remember much about the actual plot). In particular, I'm pretty sure that this was about a single huge tree and not a forest. Also, I don't remember the tree being hostile in any way, but it is possible that it was inhabited by some hostile creatures.

Comment: It was the reference to being frozen in time, revived by lightning and general tree-theme

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's [*The Stone God Awakens*](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Stone-Awakens-Philip-Jose-Farmer/dp/B0015K9834) by Philip Jose Farmer. The first review on the Amazon link I've given includes all of the elements that you mention.

[image: Stone God Front Cover]
[image: The Stone God back cover]

Comment: Thanks for posting the book cover - what a great plot hook!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Out of curiosity, did you happen to know the book and recognized it or did you do a search based on the description? In the latter case would you mind explaining how you went about it? I tried googling various combinations of keywords with no luck.

Comment: I know the book. It's probably been 30 years since I read it, and I wouldn't necessarily have remembered it from the plot summary, but I remembered the title, which was enough of a clue.

Answer (score 2):

This plot is similar to the short story [*Extempore*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extempore) by Damon Knight. It also has a time traveller turned to stone (he stopped in time) who is worshipped as a god by, in this case, future/alternate universe humans

Comment: Are there any other details that suggest similarity?