# Sci-fi book with HUGE trees and catlike people

Tags: story-identification, novel

Trying to identify a book I read years ago. It had one male human that was (petrified?) for thousands of years. The world had ridiculously huge trees and catlike people. The only bit of steel to be found was his switchblade. Think it was published in the 70s.

Comment: It would help if you would go to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info and try answering the questions there, editing them into your question. :) You'd be amazed at the additional details you might remember.

Comment: Why don't you tell us about the story, maybe somebody here will recognize it.

Comment: What is a "Sci To book"?

Comment: @user14111 Scientific Tornado

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/49305/a-story-about-earth-in-far-future-with-a-civilization-centered-around-a-huge-tre

Answer (score 7):

It is almost certainly *The Stone God Awakens* by Philip José Farmer.
From Goodreads:

> A 20th century scientist is rendered frozen at the molecular level, and then reanimated millennia later by a freak accident to a strange world populated by sentient, anthropomorphic animals, who take his awakening to be the fulfillment of prophecy. He accepts the mantle of godhood and sets about discovering this brave new world, hoping to find clues to the past while finding his place as the last human... or is he? To find the answers he must lead his tribe of feline worshippers to the heart of a rival god- a great tree spanning half a continent.

[image]